# How do I remove "Delete" from my quick favorites without removing the shortcut?

Tags: shortcut

[image]

Out of nowhere, Delete by pressing X now shows as a quick favorite. whenever I remove this quick favorite the X shortcut is gone and cant delete stuff with X.

if I add it back manually through user settings it will re-appear as a quick favorite.

How do I fix this?

Comment: try with factory reset

Comment: When you have quick favorites open, right click on delete and enter remove from favorites.  close quick favorites, and reopen.  is delete gone?  if not you've probably hit a bug.

Comment: huh nvm, in a previous version of blender it used to remove the shortcut when removing it from quick favorites but it doesnt do that anymore. i dont remember which version tho